How can I show elements from an array in a Form
I have changed the elements in Firebase in the Cruceros document so that instead of being descripcionQueHacer1, descripcionQueHacer2, etc., it is an array called descripcionQueHacer with all the elements but I don't know how to make it display, I had to delete some code but is still understandable,this is my code:
edit-crucero.page.html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/gestor-cruceros"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Editar Crucero</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="saveChanges()">
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Crucero</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Nombre del Crucero:" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade el nombre del Crucero" name="name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Subtitulo</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Subtitulo del Crucero" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade el subtitulo del Crucero" name="subtitle" formControlName="subtitle"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Imagen del Crucero</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Imagen del Crucero" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la imagen del Crucero" name="imagenCrucero" formControlName="imagenCrucero"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Descripción</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Descripción del Crucero" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la descripción del Crucero" name="descripcion" formControlName="descripcion"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Imagen de la Descripción</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Imagen de la Descripción" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la imagen de la descripcion" name="imagenDescripcion" formControlName="imagenDescripcion"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Título Que Hacer 1</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Título Que Hacer 1" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade el titulo de Que Hacer 1" name="tituloQueHacer1" formControlName="tituloQueHacer1"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Imagen Que Hacer 1</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Imagen Que Hacer 1" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la imagen de Que Hacer 1" name="imagenQueHacer1" formControlName="imagenQueHacer1"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Descripción Que Hacer 1</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Descripción Que Hacer 1" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la descripcion de Que Hacer 1" name="descripcionQueHacer1" formControlName="descripcionQueHacer1"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" color="success">Guardar Cambios</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>

edit-crucero.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { CrucerosService } from '../cruceros.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-crucero',
  templateUrl: './edit-crucero.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-crucero.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterLink]
})
export class EditCruceroPage implements OnInit {

  cruceroId: string = "";
  crucero: any = {};
  editForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private crucerosService: CrucerosService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      subtitle: [''],
      imagenCrucero: [''],
      descripcion: [''],
      imagenDescripcion: [''],
      tituloQueHacer1: [''],
      imagenQueHacer1: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer1: [''],
      tituloQueHacer2: [''],
      imagenQueHacer2: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer2: [''],
      tituloQueHacer3: [''],
      imagenQueHacer3: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer3: [''],
      tituloQueHacer4: [''],
      imagenQueHacer4: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer4: [''],
      tituloQueHacer5: [''],
      imagenQueHacer5: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer5: [''],
      tituloQueHacer6: [''],
      imagenQueHacer6: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer6: [''],
      tituloCamarotes1: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes1: [''],
      imagenCamarotes1: [''],
      tituloCamarotes2: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes2: [''],
      imagenCamarotes2: [''],
      tituloCamarotes3: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes3: [''],
      imagenCamarotes3: [''],
      tituloCamarotes4: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes4: [''],
      imagenCamarotes4: [''],
      tituloCamarotes5: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes5: [''],
      imagenCamarotes5: [''],
      tituloCamarotes6: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes6: [''],
      imagenCamarotes6: [''],
      tituloCamarotes7: [''],
      descripcionCamarotes7: [''],
      imagenCamarotes7: [''],
      plano2: [''],
      plano3: [''],
      plano4: [''],
      plano5: [''],
      plano6: [''],
      plano7: [''],
      plano8: [''],
      plano9: [''],
      plano10: [''],
      plano11: [''],
      plano12: [''],
      plano13: [''],
      plano14: [''],
      plano15: [''],
      plano16: [''],
      plano17: [''],
      plano18: [''],
      plano19: [''],
      plano20: [''],
      lugar1: [''],
      lugar2: [''],
      lugar3: [''],
      lugar4: [''],
      lugar5: [''],
      lugar6: [''],
      lugar7: [''],
      lugar8: [''],
      precioLugar1: [''],
      precioLugar2: [''],
      precioLugar3: [''],
      precioLugar4: [''],
      precioLugar5: [''],
      precioLugar6: [''],
      precioLugar7: [''],
      precioLugar8: [''],
      puertos1: [''],
      puertos2: [''],
      puertos3: [''],
      puertos4: [''],
      puertos5: [''],
      puertos6: [''],
      puertos7: [''],
      puertos8: ['']
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cruceroId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    this.loadCrucero();
  }

  async loadCrucero() {
    try {
      const cruceroData = await this.crucerosService.obtenerCruceros();
      this.crucero = cruceroData.find(c => c.id === this.cruceroId);
      if (this.crucero) {
        this.editForm.patchValue({
          name: this.crucero.name,
          subtitle: this.crucero.subtitle,
          imagenCrucero: this.crucero.imagenCrucero,
          descripcion: this.crucero.descripcion,
          imagenDescripcion: this.crucero.imagenDescripcion,
          tituloQueHacer1: this.crucero.tituloQueHacer1,
          imagenQueHacer1: this.crucero.imagenQueHacer1,
          descripcionQueHacer1: this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer1,
          tituloQueHacer2: this.crucero.tituloQueHacer2,
          imagenQueHacer2: this.crucero.imagenQueHacer2,
          descripcionQueHacer2: this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer2,
          tituloQueHacer3: this.crucero.tituloQueHacer3,
          imagenQueHacer3: this.crucero.imagenQueHacer3,
          descripcionQueHacer3: this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer3,
          tituloQueHacer4: this.crucero.tituloQueHacer4,
          imagenQueHacer4: this.crucero.imagenQueHacer4,
          descripcionQueHacer4: this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer4,
          tituloQueHacer5: this.crucero.tituloQueHacer5,
          imagenQueHacer5: this.crucero.imagenQueHacer5,
          descripcionQueHacer5: this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer5,
          tituloQueHacer6: this.crucero.tituloQueHacer6,
          imagenQueHacer6: this.crucero.imagenQueHacer6,
          descripcionQueHacer6: this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer6,
          tituloCamarotes1: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes1,
          descripcionCamarotes1: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes1,
          imagenCamarotes1: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes1,
          tituloCamarotes2: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes2,
          descripcionCamarotes2: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes2,
          imagenCamarotes2: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes2,
          tituloCamarotes3: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes3,
          descripcionCamarotes3: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes3,
          imagenCamarotes3: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes3,
          tituloCamarotes4: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes4,
          descripcionCamarotes4: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes4,
          imagenCamarotes4: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes4,
          tituloCamarotes5: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes5,
          descripcionCamarotes5: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes5,
          imagenCamarotes5: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes5,
          tituloCamarotes6: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes6,
          descripcionCamarotes6: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes6,
          imagenCamarotes6: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes6,
          tituloCamarotes7: this.crucero.tituloCamarotes7,
          descripcionCamarotes7: this.crucero.descripcionCamarotes7,
          imagenCamarotes7: this.crucero.imagenCamarotes7,
          plano2: this.crucero.plano2,
          plano3: this.crucero.plano3,
          plano4: this.crucero.plano4,
          plano5: this.crucero.plano5,
          plano6: this.crucero.plano6,
          plano7: this.crucero.plano7,
          plano8: this.crucero.plano8,
          plano9: this.crucero.plano9,
          plano10: this.crucero.plano10,
          plano11: this.crucero.plano11,
          plano12: this.crucero.plano12,
          plano13: this.crucero.plano13,
          plano14: this.crucero.plano14,
          plano15: this.crucero.plano15,
          plano16: this.crucero.plano16,
          plano17: this.crucero.plano17,
          plano18: this.crucero.plano18,
          plano19: this.crucero.plano19,
          plano20: this.crucero.plano20,
          lugar1: this.crucero.lugar1,
          lugar2: this.crucero.lugar2,
          lugar3: this.crucero.lugar3,
          lugar4: this.crucero.lugar4,
          lugar5: this.crucero.lugar5,
          lugar6: this.crucero.lugar6,
          lugar7: this.crucero.lugar7,
          lugar8: this.crucero.lugar8,
          precioLugar1: this.crucero.precioLugar1,
          precioLugar2: this.crucero.precioLugar2,
          precioLugar3: this.crucero.precioLugar3,
          precioLugar4: this.crucero.precioLugar4,
          precioLugar5: this.crucero.precioLugar5,
          precioLugar6: this.crucero.precioLugar6,
          precioLugar7: this.crucero.precioLugar7,
          precioLugar8: this.crucero.precioLugar8,
          puertos1: this.crucero.puertos1,
          puertos2: this.crucero.puertos2,
          puertos3: this.crucero.puertos3,
          puertos4: this.crucero.puertos4,
          puertos5: this.crucero.puertos5,
          puertos6: this.crucero.puertos6,
          puertos7: this.crucero.puertos7,
          puertos8: this.crucero.puertos8
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading crucero:', error);
    }
  }

  async saveChanges() {
    if (this.editForm.invalid) {
      console.log('Formulario inválido');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const formData = this.editForm.value;

      await this.crucerosService.actualizarCrucero(this.cruceroId, formData);
      
      this.router.navigate(['/gestor-cruceros']);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error guardando cambios:', error);
    }
  }
}

cruceros.service.ts
import { inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { addDoc, collection, doc, Firestore, getDoc, getDocs, orderBy, query, setDoc } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CrucerosService {
    private firestore = inject(Firestore);
    public idCrucero: string = "";

    async guardarCrucero(
        idCrucero: any, 
        name: any, 
        subtitle: any, 
        imagenCrucero: any, 
        descripcion: any, 
        imagenDescripcion: any, 
        tituloQueHacer1: any,
        imagenQueHacer1: any,
        descripcionQueHacer1: any,
        tituloQueHacer2: any,
        imagenQueHacer2: any,
        descripcionQueHacer2: any,
        tituloQueHacer3: any,
        imagenQueHacer3: any,
        descripcionQueHacer3: any,
        tituloQueHacer4: any,
        imagenQueHacer4: any,
        descripcionQueHacer4: any,
        tituloQueHacer5: any,
        imagenQueHacer5: any,
        descripcionQueHacer5: any,
        tituloQueHacer6: any,
        imagenQueHacer6: any,
        descripcionQueHacer6: any,
        tituloCamarotes1: any,
        descripcionCamarotes1: any,
        imagenCamarotes1: any,
        tituloCamarotes2: any,
        descripcionCamarotes2: any,
        imagenCamarotes2: any,
        tituloCamarotes3: any,
        descripcionCamarotes3: any,
        imagenCamarotes3: any,
        tituloCamarotes4: any,
        descripcionCamarotes4: any,
        imagenCamarotes4: any,
        tituloCamarotes5: any,
        descripcionCamarotes5: any,
        imagenCamarotes5: any,
        tituloCamarotes6: any,
        descripcionCamarotes6: any,
        imagenCamarotes6: any,
        tituloCamarotes7: any,
        descripcionCamarotes7: any,
        imagenCamarotes7: any,
        plano2: any,
        plano3: any,
        plano4: any,
        plano5: any,
        plano6: any,
        plano7: any,
        plano8: any,
        plano9: any,
        plano10: any,
        plano11: any,
        plano12: any,
        plano13: any,
        plano14: any,
        plano15: any,
        plano16: any,
        plano17: any,
        plano18: any,
        plano19: any,
        plano20: any,
        lugar1: any,
        lugar2: any,
        lugar3: any,
        lugar4: any,
        lugar5: any,
        lugar6: any,
        lugar7: any,
        lugar8: any,
        precioLugar1: any,
        precioLugar2: any,
        precioLugar3: any,
        precioLugar4: any,
        precioLugar5: any,
        precioLugar6: any,
        precioLugar7: any,
        precioLugar8: any,
        puertos1: any,
        puertos2: any,
        puertos3: any,
        puertos4: any,
        puertos5: any,
        puertos6: any,
        puertos7: any,
        puertos8: any
    ) {
        const obj ={
            "idCrucero" : idCrucero,
            "name" : name,
            "subtitle" : subtitle,
            "imagenCrucero" : imagenCrucero,
            "descripcion" : descripcion,
            "imagenDescripcion" : imagenDescripcion,
            "tituloQueHacer1" : tituloQueHacer1,
            "imagenQueHacer1" : imagenQueHacer1,
            "descripcionQueHacer1" : descripcionQueHacer1,
            "tituloQueHacer2" : tituloQueHacer2,
            "imagenQueHacer2" : imagenQueHacer2,
            "descripcionQueHacer2" : descripcionQueHacer2,
            "tituloQueHacer3" : tituloQueHacer3,
            "imagenQueHacer3" : imagenQueHacer3,
            "descripcionQueHacer3" : descripcionQueHacer3,
            "tituloQueHacer4" : tituloQueHacer4,
            "imagenQueHacer4" : imagenQueHacer4,
            "descripcionQueHacer4" : descripcionQueHacer4,
            "tituloQueHacer5" : tituloQueHacer5,
            "imagenQueHacer5" : imagenQueHacer5,
            "descripcionQueHacer5" : descripcionQueHacer5,
            "tituloQueHacer6" : tituloQueHacer6,
            "imagenQueHacer6" : imagenQueHacer6,
            "descripcionQueHacer6" : descripcionQueHacer6,
            "tituloCamarotes1" : tituloCamarotes1,
            "descripcionCamarotes1" : descripcionCamarotes1,
            "imagenCamarotes1" : imagenCamarotes1,
            "tituloCamarotes2" : tituloCamarotes2,
            "descripcionCamarotes2" : descripcionCamarotes2,
            "imagenCamarotes2" : imagenCamarotes2,
            "tituloCamarotes3" : tituloCamarotes3,
            "descripcionCamarotes3" : descripcionCamarotes3,
            "imagenCamarotes3" : imagenCamarotes3,
            "tituloCamarotes4" : tituloCamarotes4,
            "descripcionCamarotes4" : descripcionCamarotes4,
            "imagenCamarotes4" : imagenCamarotes4,
            "tituloCamarotes5" : tituloCamarotes5,
            "descripcionCamarotes5" : descripcionCamarotes5,
            "imagenCamarotes5" : imagenCamarotes5,
            "tituloCamarotes6" : tituloCamarotes6,
            "descripcionCamarotes6" : descripcionCamarotes6,
            "imagenCamarotes6" : imagenCamarotes6,
            "tituloCamarotes7" : tituloCamarotes7,
            "descripcionCamarotes7" : descripcionCamarotes7,
            "imagenCamarotes7" : imagenCamarotes7,
            "plano2" : plano2,
            "plano3" : plano3,
            "plano4" : plano4,
            "plano5" : plano5,
            "plano6" : plano6,
            "plano7" : plano7,
            "plano8" : plano8,
            "plano9" : plano9,
            "plano10" : plano10,
            "plano11" : plano11,
            "plano12" : plano12,
            "plano13" : plano13,
            "plano14" : plano14,
            "plano15" : plano15,
            "plano16" : plano16,
            "plano17" : plano17,
            "plano18" : plano18,
            "plano19" : plano19,
            "plano20" : plano20,
            "lugar1": lugar1,
            "lugar2": lugar2,
            "lugar3": lugar3,
            "lugar4": lugar4,
            "lugar5": lugar5,
            "lugar6": lugar6,
            "lugar7": lugar7,
            "lugar8": lugar8,
            "precioLugar1": precioLugar1,
            "precioLugar2": precioLugar2,
            "precioLugar3": precioLugar3,
            "precioLugar4": precioLugar4,
            "precioLugar5": precioLugar5,
            "precioLugar6": precioLugar6,
            "precioLugar7": precioLugar7,
            "precioLugar8": precioLugar8,
            "puertos1": puertos1,
            "puertos2": puertos2,
            "puertos3": puertos3,
            "puertos4": puertos4,
            "puertos5": puertos5,
            "puertos6": puertos6,
            "puertos7": puertos7,
            "puertos8": puertos8
        };

        const Ref = collection(this.firestore, 'Cruceros');
        const docRef = await addDoc(Ref, obj);
        this.idCrucero = docRef.id;
        console.log(idCrucero)
    }

    async obtenerCruceros(){
        const Ref = collection(this.firestore, 'Cruceros');
        const q = query(Ref, orderBy('name'));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        const cruceros = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id:doc.id, ...doc.data()}));
        return cruceros
    }

    async actualizarCrucero(id: string, formData: any) {
        const cruceroRef = doc(this.firestore, 'Cruceros', id.toString()); 
        await setDoc(cruceroRef, formData, { merge: true });
    }

    async obtenerCruceroPorId(id: string) {
        const Ref = doc(this.firestore, 'Cruceros', id);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(Ref);
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          return docSnap.data();
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!");
          return null;
        }
      }
}


It can be done easily using FormArray. Refer below code(You might have to make a few changes as per your specific requirement):
component.ts

Define a FormArray for descripcionQueHacer in the form group.
Create a getter for descripcionQueHacer to easily access the FormArray.
Add a method addDescripcionQueHacer to add new items to the descripcionQueHacer array.
In loadCrucero, populate the descripcionQueHacer array with the data from the server.



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { CrucerosService } from '../cruceros.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-crucero',
  templateUrl: './edit-crucero.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-crucero.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterLink]
})
export class EditCruceroPage implements OnInit {

  cruceroId: string = "";
  crucero: any = {};
  editForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private crucerosService: CrucerosService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      subtitle: [''],
      imagenCrucero: [''],
      descripcion: [''],
      imagenDescripcion: [''],
      descripcionQueHacer: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cruceroId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    this.loadCrucero();
  }

  get descripcionQueHacer(): FormArray {
    return this.editForm.get('descripcionQueHacer') as FormArray;
  }

  addDescripcionQueHacer(descripcion: string) {
    this.descripcionQueHacer.push(this.fb.group({
      descripcion: [descripcion]
    }));
  }

  async loadCrucero() {
    try {
      const cruceroData = await this.crucerosService.obtenerCruceros();
      this.crucero = cruceroData.find(c => c.id === this.cruceroId);
      if (this.crucero) {
        this.editForm.patchValue({
          name: this.crucero.name,
          subtitle: this.crucero.subtitle,
          imagenCrucero: this.crucero.imagenCrucero,
          descripcion: this.crucero.descripcion,
          imagenDescripcion: this.crucero.imagenDescripcion,
        });

        this.crucero.descripcionQueHacer.forEach((descripcion: string) => {
          this.addDescripcionQueHacer(descripcion);
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading crucero:', error);
    }
  }

  async saveChanges() {
    if (this.editForm.invalid) {
      console.log('Formulario inválido');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const formData = this.editForm.value;

      await this.crucerosService.actualizarCrucero(this.cruceroId, formData);
      
      this.router.navigate(['/gestor-cruceros']);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error guardando cambios:', error);
    }
  }
}



component.html

Use formArrayName to bind the descripcionQueHacer array.
Use *ngFor to iterate over the descripcionQueHacer array and create input fields for each item.



<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/gestor-cruceros"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Editar Crucero</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="saveChanges()">
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Crucero</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Nombre del Crucero:" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade el nombre del Crucero" name="name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Subtitulo</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Subtitulo del Crucero" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade el subtitulo del Crucero" name="subtitle" formControlName="subtitle"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Imagen del Crucero</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Imagen del Crucero" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la imagen del Crucero" name="imagenCrucero" formControlName="imagenCrucero"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Descripción</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Descripción del Crucero" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la descripción del Crucero" name="descripcion" formControlName="descripcion"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Imagen de la Descripción</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Imagen de la Descripción" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la imagen de la descripcion" name="imagenDescripcion" formControlName="imagenDescripcion"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Descripción Que Hacer</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <div formArrayName="descripcionQueHacer">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of descripcionQueHacer.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <ion-input label="Descripción Que Hacer" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Añade la descripcion de Que Hacer" formControlName="descripcion"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" color="success">Guardar Cambios</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>



